# Retrieve coords for google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have this data... 45°25'02.98" 10°11'30.39", how can retrive Latitude and Longitude to pass at gLatLng?

Comment: You might want to accept some answers to your previous questions before you ask new ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this formula

```
lat = 45 + (25 / 60) + (2.98 / 3600)
lng = 10 + (11 / 60) + (30.29 / 3600)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or punch in address here and get coords back.

http://itouchmap.com/latlong.html